# What are these Ottoman artifacts and what, if any, is their significance and inscriptions?

Tags: identification, ottoman-empire, turkey

A relative has these items - what is the metal thing used for, and what language is inscribed on it? Does the belt have any naval importance?

[image: Ottoman metal stacking object]
[image: Ottoman beaded belt]
[image: Higher resolution of metal inscription]

Comment: Better resolution images on the text on the metallic object might be helpful for identification. The back of the belt is mirror imaged, and the buckle appears to be upside down. The metallic object may be a stacking lunch box, similar to the [Tiffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiffin_carrier) boxes. A belt similar to this can be seen on [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/listing/617774634/vintage-traditional-glass-beaded-womens)

Comment: @justCal I added a higher resolution of a portion of the inscription, thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be [Mongol Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_script)

Comment: The anchor might also be related to Ankara.

Comment: The belt buckle is very similar to one [shown at](https://www.ottoman-uniforms.com/1909-till-1916-ottoman-navy/) Ottoman Uniforms.com which was used between 1909 and 1916.